# Loading CSV as point vector using QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, import

I have a .csv file with more than 2000 rows that I would like to upload to QGIS as point vector. When I add the text layer it loads only 1 value.
I have selected as `"X field"` the X coordinate and as `"Y field"` the Y coordinate.

[image: csv file]

[image: text layer]

[image: the only point on qgis]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tick "la virgola è il separatore decimal" as your fields `field_9` and `field_12` without this option need point as decimal separator.