# How to create a cross referencing database between lat and long and shapefile

Tags: qgis, intersection

Here's the issue. I have 500,000 lat-long data points and I want to figure out what census block they are in. I have a shapefile with said census blocks. I also have downloaded QGIS.

But, what I can't figure out is how to use the intersection tool to create a new file with my lat-long points and the corresponding census block in them. I want to put it in an Excel format, so I can use pivot tables on it.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is `Menu Vector / Datamanagement Tools / Join attributes by location`. Set the points as input and the polygon as overlay layer. As Geometric predicate, use within. Choose `fields to add`, for `Join type` use `Take attributes of the first matching feature only (one-to-one)`. If you want, define a prefix.

*Screenshot: output will by a copy of the point-layer with added attribute `name` (or whatever you chose) of the polygon it lies within:*
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do my points need to be a specific file type? Right now, the lat-long are in .csv.

Comment: You must load the  csv file as point layer. There are some answer about this, see e.g.: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/403989/88814 or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397331/load-csv-as-point-vector-on-qgis

Comment: Okay. I've created the joined layer file, how do I extract the data into a .csv format?

Comment: Just export: `Right click layer / Export / Save features as...`